# Current links not staying active

Tags: css, function, hyperlink

I'm trying to have my links change on mouse hover and then change when clicked and STAY until a new link is clicked. The links start a bit transparent and when hovered it turns full opacity with a bottom border or 5. When I click a link however it does not stay active even though I used:

```
nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a.current {
opacity:1;
border-bottom:5px solid #37DD57;
position: relative;
top: 1px; 
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or a script function I need to call? Here's my rough draft website: http://envycosmetics.zxq.net/Website/webpages/index.html

Answer (score 0):

An active link is only active until another link is clicked or until the window object is destroyed. Your links are reloading the page with a new URL, therefore on page load none of your links are "active". You'll need to use some URL detection and style them that way, either client side or server side.

Try this :

```
var _links    = ['news','about','gallery'], // etc..
    _pagename = null,
    i         = 0,
    max       = _links.length;

for(; i<max; i++) {
    _pagename = window.location.pathname.match(/[a-z]+(?=.html)/);
    if (_pagename == _links[i]) {
        document.getElementById(_pagename).childNodes[0].className = 'current';
    }
}
```

Visit http://envycosmetics.zxq.net/Website/webpages/gallery.html, paste the above code in your console and hit enter, and you should see the Gallery tab get highlighted.

Comment: He already has it set up to work with the `.current` class, so he would simply need to add `class="current"` to the current page's `a` element.

Comment: I would definitely suggest either adding the class manually on each page if they're hardcoded, or doing that in PHP/etc, rather than in JS.

Comment: PHP would make more sense but the OP didn't specify any server-side language in the question or with a tag. For all we know it's a Ruby site or JSP.